# Dragon riding tamed Wolf problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I recently tried to summon an EnderDragon riding a tamed Wolf, but for an unknown reason, it doesn't work. Here is what I wrote in the command block:

```
/summon ~ ~ ~ EnderDragon {Riding:{ID:"Wolf"} {Owner:Kimatuy}}
```

I don't know where my error is, please show me the correct way if possible!

Comment: Winch version are you using? The riding mechanic was changed to a passenger mechanic for 1.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You closed the NBT data for the wolf and then opened another compound illegally (missing a comma as well as a tag-name for it). You just separate tags at the same depth with commas.

The entity ID comes at the start of the `/summon` command:

```
/summon <entity> X Y Z {dataTags}
```

As well, all tags are case-sensitive; it's `id` rather than `ID`. Fixed command for pre-1.9:

```
/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"Wolf",Owner:"Kimatuy"}}
```

If you're using 1.9, the `Riding` tag has been replaced with `Passengers`, which is a list rather than a compound (allowing multiple passengers at the same depth) as well as reversing the stack order. You'd summon the host first instead of the top-most entity:

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~ ~ {Owner:"Kimatuy",Passengers:[{id:"EnderDragon"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but in fact when the command is run the dog would be killed by the dragon. But something is weird: after the dragon killed the dog, it would like get off of my viewing distance in a fraction of second (kind of like when an enderman teleports). Is it a glitch or the program (minecraft) is running normally?